# Update sequence based on pattern SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, while-loop

I was not able to quote correct tile for the question.

Below is my table.

[image]

Expected Output : With ID and `SequenceNo` column. Was unable to upload image.

```
ID  Act SequenceNo1
1   1   1
2   2   NULL
3   3   NULL
4   4   NULL
5   1   5
6   2   NULL
7   3   NULL
8   4   NULL
9   5   NULL
10  6   NULL
11  5   11
12  6   NULL
13  1   13
14  2   NULL
15  3   NULL
16  4   NULL
17  5   NULL
18  6   NULL
19  1   19
20  2   NULL
21  3   NULL
22  4   NULL
23  5   NULL
24  6   NULL
```

At the start last column `SequenceNo` is NULL.`

My requirement is to update value of `ID` column to `SequenceNo` column whenever new series of `Act` column is started.

`Act` column has value of 1 to 6. There can be case where any number from 1 to 6 is missing from `Act`.

Example1 : `ID` 1 to 4 - `Act` is correct but, in next row (`ID`=5) `Act` is restarted. Hence need to update `SequenceNo` column.

Example2 : `ID` 5 to 10 are correct. But next row (`ID`=11;`Act`=5) has new sequence hence need to update `SequenceNo` column.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp 
(
    ID int 
    , ScheduleID varchar(50)
    ,DCNumber VARCHAR(50)
    , BuildingID varchar(10)
    , StoreNumber int
    , [DayOfWeek] int
    , [Tm] varchar(10)
    ,[Act] int
    , SequenceNo int

)

INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 1,'WAS',9003,900301,254,1,'00:00',1,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 2,'WAS',9003,900301,254,1,'00:00',2,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 3,'WAS',9003,900301,254,1,'00:00',3,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 4,'WAS',9003,900301,254,1,'00:00',4,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 5,'WAS',9003,900301,254,2,'00:00',1,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 6,'WAS',9003,900301,254,2,'00:00',2,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 7,'WAS',9003,900301,254,2,'00:00',3,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 8,'WAS',9003,900301,254,2,'00:00',4,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 9,'WAS',9003,900301,254,2,'00:00',5,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 10,'WAS',9003,900301,254,2,'00:00',6,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 11,'WAS',9003,900301,254,3,'00:00',5,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 12,'WAS',9003,900301,254,3,'00:00',6,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 13,'WAS',9003,900301,254,4,'00:00',1,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 14,'WAS',9003,900301,254,4,'00:00',2,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 15,'WAS',9003,900301,254,4,'00:00',3,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 16,'WAS',9003,900301,254,4,'00:00',4,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 17,'WAS',9003,900301,254,5,'00:00',5,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 18,'WAS',9003,900301,254,5,'00:00',6,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 19,'WAS',9003,900301,254,6,'00:00',1,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 20,'WAS',9003,900301,254,6,'00:00',2,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 21,'WAS',9003,900301,254,6,'00:00',3,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 22,'WAS',9003,900301,254,6,'00:00',4,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 23,'WAS',9003,900301,254,7,'00:00',5,NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 24,'WAS',9003,900301,254,7,'00:00',6,NULL
```

I have build one logic but that is time consuming.

```
DECLARE  @Act INT, @iStart INT, @iMax INT, @iFirst INT
    SET @iFirst = 7
    SET @iMax = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #tmp)
    SET @iStart = 1
    WHILE(@iStart <= @iMax)
    BEGIN   
        SET @Act = (SELECT Act FROM #tmp WHERE ID = @iStart) 
        IF(@iFirst > @Act )
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #tmp SET SequenceNo = @iStart WHERE ID = @iStart     
        END
        SET @iFirst = @Act
        SET @iStart = @iStart + 1
    END
```

I am looking out for any alternative optimized solution.

Comment: MySQL is a different rdbms product, it's got nothing to do with ms sql server. Pls only use relevant product tags in your question.

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with? Also, can you edit your question to add sample data as DDL+DML?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has ranking and window functions like ROW_NUMBER, RANK, LEAD,LAG etc which make this query trivial. It's also the earliest supported SQL Server version. There *are* ways to detect breaks in sequences without loops in previous versions, although they are harder to write. Perhaps you should move to a supported server version? Eg, finding a break in the sequence just needs to find rows where `Act - LAG(Act,1)` is different than 1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks. But I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5520.0 (X64)  version. Any other help?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
update tupd
set
    SequenceNo = tupd.ID
from (
    select
    *
        , LAG(t.Act, 1, null) over(order by t.ID) as LagAct
    from #tmp t
) tt
inner join #tmp tupd on tt.ID = tupd.ID
where tt.Act < tt.LagAct


select
*
from #tmp tt
order by tt.ID
```

Comment: My version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5520.0 (X64)  . I am getting error as "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled."

Comment: @AK47 as I mentioned in the comments, these aren't PDW features, these are SQL Server 2012+ features. You are running a very old (10 years) unsupported version. This makes writing an answer harder. You could try self joins over the matching columns to try and find previous-next rows in a sequence

Answer (score 0):

```sql
;WITH CTE 
AS 
(
    SELECT  ID,Act,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [DayOfWeek] ORDER BY Act) RN
    FROM    #tmp
)
UPDATE t
SET t.SequenceNo = t.id
FROM #tmp t
inner join CTE C
    ON t.ID = C.ID
WHERE C.RN = 1
```

Comment: I want value of ID field into SequenceNo field. You query is not helping me.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the sequence should look like? Also updated my answer. Check now if it does what you want.

Comment: Added expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can find breaks in the `Act` sequence if you compare the current row with the previous. In current SQL Server versions, ie 2012+ you can do that with the LAG() method. In previous versions, you have to perform a self join on the current ID value and its previous value. If the difference between the current and previous `Act` values isn't 1, there is a break in the sequence. This only works if there are no gaps in ID.

This query will return 1 in the SeqBreak column for each row where `Act` restarts

```
select 
    t1.ID,
    t1.SequenceNo ,
    case when t1.act = t2.act+1 then '0' else '1' end as SeqBreak
from #tmp t1 left join #tmp t2 on t1.id=t2.id+1
```

You can use this in a CTE to select only the rows where `Act` breaks. You can update the CTE directly, at least in SQL Server 2014.

```
with x as (
    select 
        t1.ID,
        t1.SequenceNo ,
        case when t1.act = t2.act+1 then '0' else '1' end as SeqBreak
    from #tmp t1 left join #tmp t2 on t1.id=t2.id+1 )
update x
set SequenceNo=x.ID
where seqbreak=1 and id>1
```

If that doesn't work with SQL Server 2008, you'll have to join between the cte and the table:

```
with x as (
    select 
        t1.ID,
        t1.SequenceNo ,
        case when t1.act = t2.act+1 then '0' else '1' end as SeqBreak
    from #tmp t1 left join #tmp t2 on t1.id=t2.id+1 )
update #tmp
set SequenceNo=x.ID
from #tmp inner join x on x.ID=#tmp.ID
where seqbreak=1 and #tmp.id>1
```

The equivalent query using LAG(), one of the windowing functions in SQL Server 2012 is simpler and twice as fast, since it avoids the self join:

```
with x as (
    select 
        ID,
        SequenceNo ,
        case when act = 1 +LAG(act,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID)  then '0' else '1' end as SeqBreak
    from #tmp)
update x
set SequenceNo=x.ID
where seqbreak=1 and id>1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your question correctly below query should fetch the desired result.

```
             update t3 set sequenceno = t3.id 
from
            #temp t1
            cross apply (select id+1 as idsum 
        from #temp 
            tmp where t1.id = tmp.id)t2
            inner join #temp t3
            on t3.id = t2.idsum
where t1.act>t3.act
```